# Simple GitHub workflow to get started with

Tags: git, github

I've worked almost a year as a developer, and during that time I've worked only with Subversion as version control. Now I'm in a 2-man project where we just set up a GitHub repository, and I'm looking for an *easy* workflow just to get started - until I have had the time to learn all the small nuances of Git that I believe will make it great.

I've been searching for "Git Workflow" but all I can find is big documents that seem to teach the most advanced way of working with Git.

If anyone has any ideas or tips on good resources on this I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://gitref.org is great for teaching you the basics of git.

As for workflow, if you're coming from SVN all I can say is branches.  Branch your ass off.  Every time you start a new bug, feature, whatever, start a new branch off of the current master.  Don't work in master directly.  It's much easier to do merges than it is to sort out a signle branch that's had a dozen different things worked in it.  If you get used to branching now, it'll be very easy for you to adapt your workflow for merging back into master to best fit your project.

Also, commit early, commit often.  You can always amend and rebase commits before you push to clean them up.  Committing ensures git is tracking your changes so you don't lose them by runnign the wrong command.  It's easy to undo a mistake if you previous version was committed, it's not easy (if not impossible) to recover if the changes were never committed.

Answer (score 1):

Top 10 Git Tutorials for Beginners - http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/

[Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: Checkout this blog on git -> https://techxposers.com/git-for-beginners/